# Сохранить остаток

Tags: delphi

Ищу строки со словом **Test** в текстовом файле: Как сохранить во второй текстовый файл остальные строки где нет слова **Test**.

Делаю так:
Var
OnovnoyF, fsave,fOstatok: TextFile;

```
// Поиск нужных строк
if (pos('Test',S) > 0) then
     writeln(fsave, S);

// Сохранения остатка
// Поиск нужных строк
if (pos('Test',S) < 0) then
     writeln(fOstatok, S);
```

Но остаток не сохраняется... Где прокол ?

Comment: и почему бы ветку `else`  к первому условию не написать?

Comment: @ teran, Получается нужно было сделать вот так: if (pos('@',S) > 0) and (pos(f,S) > 0) then writeln(f1, S) else writeln(f2, S);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pos('Test',S) < 0` - что возвращает `Pos`, если фрагмент строки не найден?

Comment: Возвращает false? правильно ?

Comment: @Денис Почему Вы готовы верить людям из Интернета, вместо того, чтобы прочитать документацию или провести эксперимент? Функция `Pos` возвращает `0`.

Comment: @ Igor, Получается нужно было сделать вот так: if (pos('@',S) > 0) and (pos(f,S) > 0) then
     writeln(f1, S)
     else
     writeln(f2, S);

Comment: @Денис Наверное - да. Этого кода нет в вопросе.

Comment: А до этого я додумался как только Вы сказали мне прочитать документацию. Кстати, сработало! Igor +++. Поставил Вам заслуженное решение задачи!